# Vue: the template root disallows v-for directives

Tags: javascript, loops, templates, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to make a simple post list component, where I use the `v-for` directive, but I'm seeing the following error:

```
"eslint-eslint: the template root disallows v-for directives"
```

How am I supposed to loop and render each post?

I'm passing `allBehaviourPosts` to the component from a Laravel backend as a prop, like this:

```html
<related-post-list :relatedBehaviourPost= {{ $relatedBehaviourPosts }}></>
```

*My component:*

```html
<template>
<div class="sidebar_related_content_container" v-for="behaviour in relatedBehaviourPosts " :key="behaviour.id" style="">
    <a class="sidebar_related_content_image" href="/conducta-canina/{{ relatedBehaviour.slug }}"  style="background-image:url('{{ behaviour.image }}');">
        <div class="black_gradient" style=""></div>
    </a>
    <div class="sidebar_related_content_text_container" style="">
        <span class="sidebar_related_content_text_title" style="">{{ behaviour.postcategory.name }}</span>
        <span class="sidebar_related_content_text_description" style="">{{ behaviour.title }}</span>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
<!--SCRIPTS-->
<script>
    export default {

        props: ['relatedBehaviourPosts'],

        data: function () {
            return {
                //data
            }
        },

        mounted() {
            console.log('Footer mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
<!--STYLES-->
<style scoped>

</style>
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In Vue 2, each component can only contain a [single root element](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#A-Single-Root-Element), which precludes [conditional rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if) or [list rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html) on the root element. You would have to wrap your list in another element (e.g., a `div`), making that the root:

```html
<template>
  <div> <!-- single root element here -->

    <div v-for="behaviour in relatedBehaviourPosts " :key="behaviour.id">
      <!-- ... -->
    </div>

  </div>
</template>
```

Also note Vue 2 does not support string interpolation in attribute bindings, so those would have to be replaced with data bindings of this syntax:

```
:ATTRIBUTE_NAME="VALUE"
```

In particular, replace this:

```html
<a href="/conducta-canina/{{ behaviour.slug }}"
   style="background-image:url('{{ behaviour.image }}');"></a> <!-- DON'T DO THIS -->
```

with this (using [ES2015 template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)):

```html
<a :href="`/conducta-canina/${behaviour.slug}`"
   :style="`background-image:url('${behaviour.image}');`"></a>
```

or with this (using string concatenation):

```html
<a :href="'/conducta-canina/' + behaviour.slug"
   :style="'background-image:url(\'' + behaviour.image + '\');'"></a>
```

[Vue 2 demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/916lolko54)

Note that Vue 3 allows multiple root nodes, so your component template would [work there](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-list-rendering?file=src/components/Posts.vue).

Answer (score 4):

I got this error sometimes ago, the problem is that the template root does not allow 'v-for' directives. The solution to use directives in a template is, you need to provide a root div to contain the element that has your directives.
This worked in my case. Check here for more info https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/valid-template-root.html

```
<template>
<!-- place a root element -->
<div>
 <div v-for='item in menu'>some items</div>
</div>
</template>
```